# Error occur in FragmentStatePagerAdapter?

Tags: android, fragmentstatepageradapter

Here is the code line where I am getting the error:

```
ImagePagerAdapter adapter = new ImagePagerAdapter(((Activity)getContext()).getFragmentManager());
```

**Error is not coming at the runTime, It comes in the project.** when I take the cursor on error and for the recommended solution. I click and the change happened in the

```
ImagePagerAdater(android.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager)
```

**Constructor** and super gives error after the change and ImagePagerAdapter class is below:

ImagePagerAdapter.java

```
public class ImagePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    public ImagePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager){
        super(fragmentManager);
    }
    @Override
        ...
}
```

**[study link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentStatePagerAdapter.html)** from where I start this

Comment: Fascinating. And which error would that be? (A.k.a. please post a stacktrace or LogCat output)

Comment: Error is not coming at the runTime. It comes in the project. when I take the cursor on it and for the recommended solution. I click and the change happened in the ImagePagerAdater(android.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager) constuctor and super gives error after did this. @Patrick

Comment: Watch out the support package you are using and unify all your codes for the version you have selected.

Comment: @haike00 : I added some detail, may be it will help you to understand the problem and The code is proper , I just added where I am getting error.

Comment: I believe you are using a mix between V4 and V13 support package. For instance, you do `public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity` (V4) but `getFragmentManager()` (V13) gets called to pass into your FragmentStatePagerAdapter.

Comment: @haike00 : both package are the same

Comment: Post your complete code, i will see what i can do.

Comment: @haike00 : I am not extands either Activity nor FragmentActivity. there is extends LinearLayout